# Logback change @timestamp format

Tags: spring, logback, spring-logback

I have this logback configuration :

```
    <appender name="CHRONO" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
     <file>${CHRONO_LOGS_FILE_NAME}</file>
     <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${CHRONO_LOGS_FILE_PATTERN}</fileNamePattern>
        <maxFileSize>${MAX_FILE_SIZE}</maxFileSize>
        <maxHistory>${MAX_HISTORY}</maxHistory>
        <totalSizeCap>${TOTAL_SIZE_CAP}</totalSizeCap>
     </rollingPolicy>
     <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <findAndRegisterJacksonModules>false</findAndRegisterJacksonModules>
        <timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss Z</timestampPattern>
        <customFields>{ "APP_NAME":"${APP_NAME}",
        "APP_VERSION":"${APP_VERSION}", "INSTANCE": "${INSTANCE}"} 
     </customFields>
    </encoder>
   </appender>
```

And my goal is to change the timestamp name into logdate and format into ISO8601 format
YYYYMM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnn+ZZ:ZZ > 2019-12-23T15:23:30.123+01:00
But I couldn't find anywhere where to do that.

```
{
"@timestamp": "2022-03-08 14:46:20 +0100",
"@version": "1",
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue just now. You can easily change the time format with editing the following line:

```
<timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss Z</timestampPattern>
```

to

```
<timestampPattern>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX</timestampPattern>
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is the pattern that you are looking for but in UTC it is showing a Z at the end of the timestamp that suggests it will show the offset for you.